# Hover image -> fade out navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my `.hover` image for the fade out navigation.

[image: 1]

now when you hover on the image which is shown above...the navigation will fade out like this

[image: 2]

This fade out could be done with

```
.header {
    top: -70px;
}
```

and when you hover the header must be

```
.header {
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You should post your HTML.

Comment: without the markup it is hard try seating the .header with position relative

Comment: Can you post what you have in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?